# raspivid doesn't include b-frames

Tags: pi-3, raspicam, raspivid, h264

I'm streaming raw h264 using `raspivid` on Raspberry Pi 3 and PiCam v1 . However, even I set the h264 profile to `main` or `high`, stream only contains I and P frames. Here is the command that I use for starting stream over TCP;

```
raspivid --verbose --framerate 10 -b 1000000 --stats --intra 50 --inline --nopreview  -t 0 -l --output tcp://0.0.0.0:5001
```

When I parse the byte stream, I only see `SPS`,`PPS`,`I-frames` and `P-frames`. How can I make raspivid to add `B-frames` also?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the [official answer](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=231368) on Raspberry Pi forum, it is not possible to include B-Frames into h264 stream since hardware encoder doesn't support it.